# Nextpeer integration error with npGetiOSVersion

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, integration, nextpeer

I heard about the Nextpeer SDK and started to integrate in my current app. However, it gives me an error. I am unable to resolve the error.

The error states:

```
-[UIDevice npGetiOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e62370
 ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDevice npGetiOSVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e62370'
```

Comment: Please come with more details

Comment: take this to the developers